# Building SiteMap in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, sharepoint-2007, sitemap

I have a website with Page A and Page B

Page B has a Link on Page A

Page B is actually a sub-sub-sub-web of Page C.

Now I am trying to make changes to Breadcrumb Navigation which is a custom User Control.

ATM I am trying to check if user is navigated to Page B from Page A then create this navigation and If Navigated from somewhere otherwise build a different Navigation. By using this property I know where a user coming from

```
Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

OK Now problem is I want to build or get Site Map of Page/web a User is navigated from so that I can add this page B title to that Breadcrumb navigation as shown below,

Page A > Page B

or it can be

Page C > Page C.1 > Page C.2 > Page B

code I am using is this,

```
        string defaultBreadcrumbHtml = "<SPAN><a class=\"ms-sitemapdirectional\" href=\"{0}\">{1}</a></SPAN>";
    string defaultSpacingHtml = "<SPAN> > </SPAN>";


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SiteMapProvider contentMapProvider = SiteMap.Providers["SPContentMapProvider"];
            StringBuilder generatedHTML = new StringBuilder();
            generatedHTML.Append("<div class=\"ms-globallinks TopBreadcrumbs\">");


            if (contentMapProvider != null)
            {
                SiteMapNode currentNode = contentMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

                if (currentNode != null)
                {

                    string[] breadcrumbTitles = new string[20]; ;
                    string[] breadcrumbUrls = new string[20];
                    int count = 0;

                    if (currentNode == contentMapProvider.RootNode)
                    {
                        breadcrumbTitles[0] = currentNode.Title;
                        breadcrumbUrls[0] = currentNode.Url;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (currentNode != contentMapProvider.RootNode)
                        {
                            if (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Contains("PageA"))
                            {
                                breadcrumbTitles[count] = "Page B";
                                breadcrumbUrls[count] = string.Format("www.Gohome.com\PageB.aspx");
                                count++;
                            }

                            breadcrumbTitles[count] = currentNode.Title;
                            breadcrumbUrls[count] = currentNode.Url;

                            if (currentNode.ParentNode != null)
                            {
                                currentNode = currentNode.ParentNode;
                                count++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        breadcrumbTitles[count] = currentNode.Title;
                        breadcrumbUrls[count] = currentNode.Url;
                    }

                    while (count >= 0)
                    {
                        generatedHTML.Append(string.Format(defaultBreadcrumbHtml, breadcrumbUrls[count], breadcrumbTitles[count]));
                        if (count != 0)
                        {
                            generatedHTML.Append(defaultSpacingHtml);
                        }
                        count--;
                    }

                    generatedHTML.Append("</div>");

                    html.Text = generatedHTML.ToString();
                }
            }
```

**But its not working properly, I tried to debug it but because I am not able to get Site Map of Web/page I came from, I am not able to get site map.
So My question is, How can I get Site Map of Website I am navigated from , so that I add another Node to it as "siteicame from > ..>  Page B"**

to get Site Map of current page i can use this but I dont want to use this as It will give SiteMap as  Site C > Site C.1 ... > Site B

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To  achieve Breadcrumb navigation  ... No need of code behind.

You can achieve through

1) Web.SiteMap
2) ASPX Page's Tabs

- 
- 
- 

If you want... i will show you sample code... ?

Comment: am afraid the only option I have is to use User Control and then do everything behind code, cheers for your answer tho :)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts.... But for such simple purpose ... Why you are gng fr different one ?

Comment: actually, I am doing some other calculations in User Control, as I dont just have Page B link on 1 page/web but on several web pages, so its kind of dynamic, so I must have to use Code logic :/